# What is the extra negation in React development code?

Tags: reactjs

I was going through the React 16 development code and found something like this

```
function resolveDispatcher() {
  var dispatcher = ReactCurrentDispatcher.current;
  !(dispatcher !== null) ? invariant(false, 'Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:\n1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)\n2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks\n3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app\nSee for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.') : void 0;
  return dispatcher;
}
```

I want to know why the developers of Facebook have used this `{!(dispatcher !== null)}`, why can't they simply use this `{(dispatcher === null)}` instead